# HTML elements not updating from ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I am trying to update some input fields on my page after performing an ajax call that returns an object.  I know the call is being made and returning the correct items, however, it is not writing those items on the textboxes.  This is how I'm setting them up after the ajax call:

```
success: function(data) {
         $('#address_LocaleID').val(data.LocaleID);
         $('#address_StreetAddress').val(data.StreetAddress);
         $('#address_Address2').val(data.Address2);
         $('#address_StreetNumber').val(data.StreetNumber);
         $('#address_BuildingNumber').val(data.BuildingNumber);
         $('#address_City').val(data.City);
         $('#address_StateProvinceID').val(data.StateProvinceID);
         $('#address_CountryID').val(data.CountryID);
         $('#address_CountyID').val(data.CountyID);
         $('#address_PostalCode').val(data.PostalCode);
         $('#address_ApplicationTypeID').val(data.ApplicationTypeID);
         $('#address_MapURL').val(data.MapURL);
         $('#address_Description').val(data.Description);
         $('#address_IsActive').val(data.IsActive);
         $('#address_DateCreated').val(data.DateCreated);
}
```

The 'data' parameter being brought back is an "Address" object from a controller.  I believe this is where the problem lies, I'm returning a C# object, but say for example, I create an alert inside the success function to spit out 'data.City', it gives me the correct value.  Where could the error lie?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

Action method:

```
        [HttpGet]
    public Address AddressGet(string guid, string id)
    {
        Guid addressID = new Guid(guid);
        Address address = new Address();
        address.LocaleID = new Guid(id);

        if (addressID == Guid.Empty)
        {
            return address;
        }
        else
        {
            address = _iRepository.Address_Get(addressID);

            return address;
        }
    }
```

There is nothing special being done, just returning an Address object.

Comment: So alerting these values always alerts correctly?

Comment: How the hell should we know? That's a bunch of elements referenced with ID's, and you're setting the value to something we have no idea what is ?

Comment: There's not really enough info here to answer the question.  A sample of the HTML containing the fields, and the JSON being returned, would help tremendously.

Comment: I know the values are being sent back correctly, that's why I added the last comment. It has nothing to do with the ID's (which are unique) or your comment whatsoever!! I also said I know the problem is the way the object is being brought back, I need to do something with it before I can use it in the manner displayed, I just don't know what to do!

Comment: Let me edit it to show the action method

Comment: @Jose: The method doesn't mean much here, without a bunch of other code that'd probably just clutter up the question.  Add a `console.log(data);` to the success function, then hit F12 to fire up your debugger and click the "console" tab.  Reload the page, and see what gets logged there.

Comment: I never knew how to use that, will do, thanks for explaining!

Comment: The console line reads '[object Object]'

Comment: Eh.  You're using IE, aren't you.  :P  In that case, try `console.dir(a)`.  And consider installing Chrome.  Its dev tools are rather awesome.

Comment: I'll second that, Chrome's debugger is much better than IE's.

Comment: Indeed it is!!!! It is bringing the complete object perfectly. The problem must be my selectors then

Answer (score 1):

Try Json.parse(data) to convert the response data into a proper javascript object literal.

Comment: The OP says `alert(data.City);` pops up the right value.  If `data` were a string, that would instead pop up "undefined".

Comment: I did see that in the OP, just figured it was worth a shot.  But if the alert is showing the right value maybe this isn't the issue.

Comment: I tried parsing the data and stringifying (?) it with Json.stringify but they still do not update.

Comment: Bummer.  What does data look like in the success function if you use a browser debugger?  Though I'm not sure how useful this will be since as you've said repeatedly, using alert shows the correct value.

Comment: Let me take a look at that

Comment: Actually, it's bring the object back perfectly, with all the fields and values.  Maybe it's not the ajax or json after all

Comment: The issue must then be with how you are accessing the inputs and setting their value.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably something from with your dom lookup make sure all the names are correct.

Also you don't tell us things like what the dom object that should be changed look like. we don't need to see your return json since it's working in the alert but I think the problem lies in when it's trying to change the values in the dom.

also make sure that the ajax call function is being called by something that is in a document ready function bracket.

```
//ajaxfunction outside of doc ready function

$(document).ready(function () {
//ajaxfunctioncall here
});
```

Comment: It's probably something simple as that.  Thanks for your help.